# Не работает ttl для движка EmbeddedRocksDB в ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

Я создаю таблицу в ClickHouse с движком EmbeddedRocksDB согласно [инструкции](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/embedded-rocksdb):

```
EmbeddedRocksDB([ttl, rocksdb_dir, read_only])

ttl - time to live for values. TTL is accepted in seconds. If TTL is 0, regular RocksDB instance is used (without TTL).
```

Создание таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE default.ttl_table
(
    key String,
    value String
)
ENGINE = EmbeddedRocksDB(10)
PRIMARY KEY key;
```

Я ожидаю, что вставленные в таблицу строки будут удаляться через 10 секунд. Однако, данные из таблицы не удаляются совсем, как будто параметр `ttl` не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

ClickHouse я запускаю в докере, используя образ: `clickhouse/clickhouse-server:23.1-alpine`

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Time-to-Live) ttl является нестрогим временем удаления, то есть гарантирует, что вставленные значения ключей останутся в базе данных как минимум ttl времени, и БД приложит усилия, чтобы удалить значения ключей как можно скорее после ttl секунд их вставки. Кроме того, записи с истёкшим сроком жизни удаляются только при сжатии.

Для того чтобы удалить истёкшие записи в ClickHouse, нужно выполнить команду: `optimize table ttl_table`, где `ttl_table` - имя таблицы с EmbeddedRocksDB-движком.